# How to inject type attribute into all script tags via javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to know how to query ALL script tags and set a random attribute. What I have tried does not work:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0].setAttribute("data-foo", "bar");
```

It only matches the first script tag. (No jQuery please. I love it, but not now. It also needs to be cross-browser so `querySelectorAll` won't work).

## Edit:

Okay, so as it turns out, pure-JavaScript query selectors only select things as they're loaded (As Kolink pointed out and thesystem explained). So I have to add the script which set's attributes after the other script tags.

Comment: Why? The HTML specification specifies that the type of a `<script>` is `text/javascript` when none is specified anyhow.

Comment: You don't need that attribute anymore, it is a default browser script language now

Comment: That's weird, because when I test it in IE8 *without* the type specified, it doesn't work. But when it *is* present, it does work.

Comment: By the time you can add the attribute on the client, the script will have already run. And it seems you already know how to select the scripts. Do you not know how to do a `for` loop?

Comment: Just because the spec says that you don't need it *anymore* doesn't mean it's going to internally update all browsers. However that would be lovely.

Comment: This is, no offense, a pretty amusing approach to this problem.

Comment: "rather than getting sloppy with the markup, I want to"... get even "sloppier" with the javascript? I really don't think this would work, you're better off doing it the right way.

Comment: @thesystem No, because the script doesn't run unless it has the `type` attribute associated with it (in IE8 and below). So once it has the `type` dynamically inserted by a file which already has `type`, only *then* will it run. But gee, now my heads spinning.

Comment: This reminds me of a question where the guy asked how to turn on the user's javascript with javascript.

Comment: @WesleyMurch Funny. No, one line of javascript in just one "master" file isn't very sloppy.

Comment: @Jacedc It depends on what you actually mean by "sloppy".

Comment: @WesleyMurch Agreed. But to me, as long as it's on 1-3 lines, I don't care what it looks like, I don't consider it sloppy.

Comment: @Jacedc: So you've verified that adding that attribute after the script has become available actually activates the script? By the way, is your document in quirks mode? Maybe that has an impact on the `type` requirement.

Comment: I have switched it both on and off without the `type` attribute and it doesn't work either time. Even so, what if the user is in quirksmode? I *really* try to avoid swaying visitors to download this browser, enable this feature, or do this or that. To me, I consider that irresponsible web authoring.

Comment: @Jacedc: So you're making the rest of your page and JavaScript quirks mode compatible?

Comment: @thesystem Excuse me, not the user, my client. My bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility would be to have your other scripts written dynamically to the page using `document.write`.

This is a classic case where `document.write` is very useful.

```
// In main/powerhouse

// list of script sources
var scripts = ["script1.js", "script2.js", "script3.js"]

for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++)
    document.write('<scr', 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="', scripts[i], '"></scr', 'ipt>');
```

Now the scripts will be written after the current running script, and will be loaded synchronously as expected.

Comment: Why use `document.write` over "real" methods like `createElement`?

Comment: @Kolink: `document.write` will cause the script to be loaded synchronously, otherwise, I'd agree.

Comment: I would do this but I'm working with a team. This is kind of hard to do without calling some major reconstruction on all of the sites. I kindof want to just make a plugin which can just **set an attribute to queried script tags**. That's all. Let's say it doesn't even have to be `type`. It could be `data-foo="bar"` but even that doesn't work with the code I used because it's only picking up the first match, which is itself, of course.

Comment: @Jacedc: I didn't understand your comment above about switching it on and off, and it not working. I'm wondering if you've verified that adding that attribute on the client actually causes the script to be activated.

Comment: Yes. It does. Keep in mind (right now) I'm only concerned with IE8, everything works on modern browsers of course.

Comment: @Jacedc: Then I think the only other possibility would be to have a second script placed after all the others that selects all the scripts and adds the attribute if needed.

Comment: Oh, so does my query only query tags that are referenced *first*??? If so that's all I need to know!!!! By the way, for future reference, just check my edited question.

Comment: @Jacedc: Yes, the document elements become available as they're loaded, and each script loads synchronously by default, which means it blocks the rest of the page from loading until it's done. This means your first script is blocking the rest of the scripts from loading, so they don't yet exist.

Comment: That's what @Kolink meant. Okay. Thanks!!

Comment: @Jacedc: You're welcome. ...but I'd still make sure your document is not in quirks mode. There's lots of stuff that can break if it is and you're not coding specifically for it.

Comment: @thesystem I absolutely agree.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

See, when the "main" script runs, the other scripts don't exist yet.

The only solution to that is to defer the type setting thing with `onload` or `DOMContentLoaded` events.

The problem with that is that by the time that fires the other scripts will have been added to the page and either run (most browsers) or ignored (older IE). Setting the `type` on them at this stage has no effect.

So instead of trying to find workarounds that will never work, why not just try writing proper HTML in the first place?

PS. Your comments about it not working in IE8 suggest that you are in Quirks Mode. Add a `<!DOCTYPE>` if you don't have one already.

Comment: I wonder if, just out of curiosity, this would work with `defer`, like if you changed all the deferred scripts type to `text/vbscript` or something...

Comment: Hmm. I don't get it. Of course the other `script` tags exist if it was physically typed in HTML. It's just a matter of querying those script tags and then adding an attribute, right?

Comment: They don't exist in that they haven't been loaded into the DOM yet - scripts block everything else while they run.